# Why does the same sed regex (after grep) fail when run in a bash script vs bash command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, grep, regular-expression

Here's the script. It is successful when I run it from the *BASH prompt*, but not in the script.  Any ideas?

---

When I say "fails," I mean the `sed regex` doesn't match anything, so there is no replaced text. When I run it on the command line, it matches.

Also, I might have an answer to this. It has to do with my `grep` alias and `GREP_OPTIONS` having a weird interplay.  I'll post back with the details on those.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((x = 101; x <= 110; x++)); do
    urls="${urls} www$x.site.com/config"
done;

curl -s ${urls} | grep -i "Git Commit" | sed -r "s/.*Git Commit<\/td><td>([^<]+).*/\1/g"
```

Comment: how does it fail? What output do you expect and what do you get? Are there any error messages? There is no grep regular expression there, just a simple string. Are you sure it is the grep that's failing?

Comment: does `$urls` already have a value when in shell mode?

Comment: added details per @terdon. And yes, I paste the whole thing into the command prompt (minus the shebang line). I'm pretty sure my `GREP_OPTIONS` are forcing `color` to `always`, while my command-line `grep` is using an alias that is automatically turning off coloring due to the piped grep output. So `sed` is getting color codes sent to it. Will give more details tonight when it let's me add an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So you've solved it? Why in the world was your grep set to `--color=always`? That's a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I think so, @terdon. The answer is longer than 600 chars thought so as a new SX user, I can't post it until I get +4 more rep or 8 hrs pass :) Agreed that `--color=always` in `GREP_OPTIONS` is ill-advised for this very reason, although I find that even in scripts I want it on almost all the time (I like my colored output). I have a lot of scripts with piped `grep` outputs (like log tails) and I took a shortcut.

Comment: That's exactly what `--color-auto` is for. It is intelligent enough to add it when you want it but not when you don't.

Comment: Right, @terdon, except for that I almost always want coloring on, even in scripts and even when I pipe it to another command.  It just requires more agile regexing when doing that. Which is no problem, I'll just have to be explicit about when I want it on.  Just makes things a bit more verbose is all. Thanks for the helpful comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually able to figure this out, and I figure I'd add it here for the next googler who bangs their head against the same wall.

I had a grep alias *and* `GREP_OPTIONS` set. This caused color highlighting to remain on in the script, even when piping to another command. That usually doesn't play nicely with `sed`.

Here's my .alias and options:

```
alias grep='grep -i --color'
export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always"
```

So when running from the script, it doesn't use the aliased command and so forces color to always be on.  So when I checked my alias and saw the `--color` option (which means `auto`, which means "don't color output that gets piped to another command" (like `sed`).

I was confused because I forgot I had set `GREP_OPTIONS` as well, so I expected the `grep` in the script to have `color` set to `auto` by default (as it would if I hadn't set the global `GREP_OPTIONS`). But not so.

Here are my new settings (I believe the `--color` flag to `GREP_OPTIONS` is redundant, but I leave it there as a reminder):

```
alias grep='grep --color=always'
export GREP_OPTIONS="--ignore-case --color"
```

That way, any time I am on the command line, I'll have highlighting on for all my greps (which is usually what I want).  But in scripts it will default to coloring only when not piped to another command. I'll still have to add --color=always to many of my scripts (since I tend to prefer highlighting in most cases, even when piping to another command, unless I don't ever see the output).